# Could not reset Wordpress user password using WP CLI

Tags: password, wp-cli, reset

I have a wordpress site (6.2.2). I forget my admin password. The site is not setup with SMTP yet, so the forget password link won't work.

I tried several ways, but none of them works.

**1. WP CLI - No luck**

- Install WP CLI, go to wordpress site folder, 'wp user list' to see all users so I can have my id, then run

> wp user update 1 --user_pass=my_clear_password

successfully -> then try to login into the WP admin using 'my_clear_password', but the login failed.

**2. Add reset password function call to functions.php: No luck**

> wp_set_password( 'my_clear_password', 1 );

**3. use WP CLI to disable Wordfence, then login again -> No luck**

**4. Use SQL Update: No luck**

> UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass=MD5('my_clear_password') WHERE ID=1;

**5. My environments:**

> Ubuntu 22, Wordpress 6.22, MySQL 8, PHP 8.

I am thinking something blocked the logins.
Any comments? Thanks!

Comment: Your SQL update used `12` instead of `1`; is that a typo? (Also, when resetting with MySQL, use an MD5 hash instead of a cleartext password; see [the documentation here](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/reset-your-password/#through-mysql-command-line).)

Comment: disable all your plugins, not just wordfence, then reset using WP-CLI and then try to login.  Why would your password just simply not work on a normal, standard WordPress site with no plugins active?  It's just not going to happen, so you probably have a plugin that's interferring. Also, use the WP-CLI reset password command: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/reset-password/

Comment: @PatJ: sorry it must be 1.yes typo. I also used MD5 mysql function. Please see the updated post.

Comment: @PaulG: will try it next week. Thanks!